# Unable to set access key and secret key for AWSCredentialsProvider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

```
g_cred1 = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key, shared_key);
AWSCredentialsProvider cred = new StaticCredentialsProvider(g_cred1);
AmazonRDSClientBuilder rdsClient1 = AmazonRDSClientBuilder
    .standard();
rdsClient1.setCredentials(cred);
```

I am tring to set the credentials to AmazonRDSClientBuilder to fetch the rds databases available. But, the credentials are not setting properly. Cred. seems to be pointing to some default user all the time and not pointing to the right one

Comment: Can you verify the access_key in IAM user, whether it points to the right user with attached access policies for the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid hard coding credentials, you can probably just get rid of lines 1 and 2. The [default credentials chain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default) will lookup credentials in your environment with safer options. For example, you can use environment variables in local dev and IAM roles in the EC2 instances.

Durable credentials (AK/SK) are harder to rotate. Even if you have multiple accounts or client-supplied credentials, temporary credentials (AK/SK + Session Token) are safer and can be obtained using STS AssumeRole variants or Amazon Cognito.

Comment: The product is such that, I need to browse the databases of different users.When I print the getaccesskey(), they are correct. But, when they are used to browse the databases, it is fetching me the default users databases.